# Entity framework inheritance TPH adding discriminator on every query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity framework model that has a base class (abstract) called "Call" and 2 subclasses called "SurvoCall" and "VoicemailCall" with discriminator "Survo" and "Voicemail" respectively.

The problem is that whenever I do an query on the calls, like for example count how many calls we got yesterday (no matter if they were Survo or Voicemail), the entity framework is adding to the query the following "where" clause:

... Discriminator in ('Survo', 'Voicemail') ....

To me it looks like unnecessary and hurting performance without having any benefit. Because if I'm querying through the Calls, (without using OfType<>), I'm telling that I want every call, no need to check the discriminator, however the entity framework still adds an "in" condition.

Is there any way around this? Because its affecting some of our queries...

Thanks!

Comment: Away around: don't use TPH.  Increase your query speed; add an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always take a look at sources for Entity Framework here to find an answer:  https://entityframework.codeplex.com/

I did a bit of debugging and research on this and it seems that you are unable to get rid of this [Dicriminator] IN ('X1', 'X2', ...., 'Xn') at all due to specifics of View generation and materialization, at least for Entity Framework 6.

Before actually generating a SELECT statement for this specific table (Call for you), it evaluates all columns that this table has and all possible types that can be derived from Call. In your case there are 2 types - SurvoCall and VoicemailCall. To get data for both entities it needs 2 different queries, because they most likely have different column sets for them in this specific table, so technically it generates 2 SELECTS here:

`SELECT Id, PhoneNumber, Duration, etc.., SurvoResult FROM [Call] where [Discriminator] = 'Survo'`

and

`SELECT Id, PhoneNumber, Duration, etc.., VoicemailDuration FROM [Call] where [Discriminator] = 'Voicemail'`.

After some internal optimizations it "concantenates" these 2 SQL queries into one that you have and concrete type selection is delegated to materializer:

`SELECT Id, PhoneNumber, Duration, etc.., SurvoResult, VoicemailDuration FROM [Call] where [Discriminator] IN ('Survo', 'Voicemail')`.

It really looks like Entity Framework internal architectural way to building queries over discriminated tables - build 1 query for each discriminator, unite, and in result you get this `IN` clause. What are the reason behind this? Probably you need to dive really deep inside Entity Framework source code or ask someone who was developing this part of code.

Conceptually, this solution makes sense - it limits your query to go through data that Entity Framework knows about and knows how to create concrete types of it, so if your Discriminator column value is incorrect - and it can be - nothing gets broken for your application. But I don't think that's the main reason.

Another interesting thing to note - you might have multi-level hierarchy of entities. Here's an example for you:

```
[Table("ProductOrService")]
public abstract class ProductOrService
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedToCartAt { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProductOrService")]
public class Level1Product : ProductOrService
{
    public string Owner { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProductOrService")]
public class Level1Service : ProductOrService
{
    public string Activator { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProductOrService")]
public abstract class Level2ProductOrService : ProductOrService
{
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProductOrService")]
public class Level2Product : Level2ProductOrService
{
    public DateTime IssuedAt { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProductOrService")]
public class Level2Service : Level2ProductOrService
{
    public DateTime ExpiresAt { get; set; }
}
```

In this example we have 2 levels of hierarchy:

```
ProductOrService (abstract)
->Level1Product
->Level1Service
->Level2ProductOrService (abstract)
->->Level2Product
->->Level2Service
```

And you can possibly have access to any level of hierarchy using dbSets:

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public IDbSet<ProductOrService> ProductsOrServices { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Level2ProductOrService> Level2ProductsOrServices { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Level1Product> Level1Products { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Level2Service> Level2Services { get; set; }
    }
```

After that calling these dbSets gives quite interesting result:

```
    var level1Root = context.ProductsOrServices
    .Where(x=>x.Price > 0);
//generates query with all possible discriminators:
{SELECT 
    ...
    FROM [dbo].[ProductOrService] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'Level1Product',N'Level2Product',N'Level2Service',N'Level1Service')) AND ([Extent1].[Price] > cast(0 as decimal(18)))}

var level2Root = context.Level2ProductsOrServices
    .Where(x => x.Price > 0);

//generates query with discriminators twice! first for root hierarchy, then for second level hierarchy!
{SELECT 
    ...
    FROM [dbo].[ProductOrService] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'Level1Product',N'Level2Product',N'Level2Service',N'Level1Service')) AND ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'Level2Product',N'Level2Service')) AND ([Extent1].[Price] > cast(0 as decimal(18)))}


var level1Products = context.Level1Products
    .Where(x => x.Price > 0);
//generates correct query with 1 discriminator
{SELECT 
    '0X0X' AS [C1], 
    ...
    FROM [dbo].[ProductOrService] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Level1Product') AND ([Extent1].[Price] > cast(0 as decimal(18)))}

var level2Services = context.Level2Services
    .Where(x => x.Price > 0);
//generates correct query with 1 discriminator
{SELECT 
    '0X0X0X' AS [C1], 
    ...
    FROM [dbo].[ProductOrService] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Level2Service') AND ([Extent1].[Price] > cast(0 as decimal(18)))}
```

As you can see, querying for base types for discriminated tables builts suboptimal queries with `IN` clause for each level of hierarchy (current + all base types) used for queried object, if it has derived types.

From the use-cases I did not really face any issues with query time for these discriminators unless you are loading a really big graph of objects with discriminators deep inside, but in these cases you can't really affect the process of query building. Overall using Table Per Hierarchy gives really much pain when your entity is not an aggregate root. The possible way to avoid it is  get rid of database handled inheritance - create an entity that has all the columns you need and handle it by yourself on C# side. This approach also has downsides, indeed, and makes code more dirty. You can probably add some layer between your real domain model and entity framework-based persistence model, check this article: http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/orm-anti-patterns-part-4-persistence-domain-model/

Sadly there seems to be no good and performant solution for using Entity Framework together with inheritance. But it's open-source, so you can try forking it and producing a nice solution :)